# uikittools cydia

Tags: iphone, cydia

What source should I to add to install uikittools ?

Comment: I think that UIKitTools is added to Cydia from the start.

Answer (score 0):

To included the UIKit framework in your Cydia project you need to add

```
[yourAppName]_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit
```

That line of code needs to be added to your makefile before you make and install the package.